# Consuming a native Android app (zxing) through a browser

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, webcam, zxing

I am currently building an ecommerce website which is based on the Magento platform. This will accessed on a tablet running Android. I want to be able to be able to scan a barcode using the built in camera and use the resulting UPC to run a product lookup in Magento.

I have a prototype running zxing on a Tomcat stack which the app can call using the [MediaStream API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) to access the tablets camera and CURL the resulting capture to zxing.

This is not ideal, as it involves additional dependencies and maintenance. It would be better if I could use the native zxing Android app. For reasons of time and cost, it will not be possible to build the entire app in Android unfortunately.

Ideally I would like to be able to embed a zxing camera view into the page. Alternatively, it might be necessary to use intents to capture the a URL request and forward it onto the zxing app using some sort of middleware app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally I would like to be able to embed a zxing camera view into the page

That is not possible.

> Alternatively, it might be necessary to use intents to capture the a URL request and forward it onto the zxing app using some sort of middleware app.

You are welcome to set up a link to `http://zxing.appspot.com/scan` to attempt to trigger the Barcode Scanner app. Not all browsers will necessarily honor this, however. And, I am not aware of any good means to get the scanned result back to your Web site.

You are also welcome to write a conventional Android app that is launched by your Web site, though that too is subject to the limitations that not all browsers support launching apps this way. That conventional app can then interact with Barcode Scanner (via `IntentIntegrator`) more directly, capturing the result. That app can then somehow get that data back to your Web server. Getting it all to stick with one browser session, though, may get tricky, particularly given N possible browser implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and digging around to see if I could use the Media Capture Stream (getUserMedia) to capture the barcode image and post it to zxing running on a Tomcat server. Unfortunately this API is [not supported](http://mobilehtml5.org/) on IOS devices.

However I did discover that the zxing Android app has a 'Custom search URL' setting. It supports substitutions:

> %s = contents, %f = format, %t = type

You can specify any target URL by pointing the zxing app to your site and grab the barcode from the request.

> http://magento.mydomain.com/barcode?sku=%s

I have looked at a couple of IOS barcode scanner apps and none of them seem to support the custom search URL functionality as the Android zxing app.

This solution is not ideal as it means the barcode scanning functionality is not baked into my app, but it is a viable workaround for the meantime.

Comment: hi can you help me fixing my custom Url. i always have `invalid value` i tried this `%s = "sample.com", %f = format, %t = type` i dont know what to put in format at type